# Laravel pass javascript variable to route

Tags: javascript

I need to pass searchWord  to  code value in laravel route

```
    searchWord = $('.searchBox').val();
    var jobs = $('input[name=jobs]:checked').val();
    console.log("num value");
    window.location.href = '{{route("post.search.index",["code"=>9987])}}';
```

i tried

```
    searchWord = $('.searchBox').val();
    var jobs = $('input[name=jobs]:checked').val();
    console.log("num value");
    window.location.href = '{{route("post.search.index",["code"=>'searchWord '])}}';
```

but it reads it as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `window.location.href = '{{route("post.search.index",["code"=>'searchWord '])}}';`

use

`window.location.href = '{{route("post.search.index",["code"=>'+searchWord+ '])}}';`
or
`window.location.href = "{{route(\"post.search.index\",[\"code\"=>"+searchWord+ "])}}";`

Comment: I get this in url  www.link.com/search/**+**searchWord**+**%20